# Does Hawking radiation from micro black hole get redshift like it stellar counterpart?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation, redshift

In a stellar black hole the hawking radiation gets redshift as it escapes the event horizon, would the same phenomenon occurs with a micro black hole? If so what is the threshold for the redshifting of hawking radiation to be negligible? Just curious can the hawking radiation be blue shifted?

Answer (score 0):

Lets clear up what stellar radiation means:

[From this link](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/r/Redshift)

> photons are manifest as either emission or absorption lines in the spectrum of an astronomical object, and by measuring the position of these spectral lines,

Stellar red shift to be measured needs a spectrum to compare the shift in the spectral lines.

> Spectral lines can also be redshifted due to the influence of *strong gravitational fields –* this is not surprisingly known as gravitational redshift. Einstein’s theory of general relativity predicts that the wavelength of electromagnetic radiation will lengthen as *it climbs out of a gravitational well*. *Photons must expend energy to escape,* but at the same time must always travel at the speed of light, so this energy must be lost through a change of frequency rather than a change in speed. If the energy of the photon decreases, the frequency also decreases (in other words, the wavelength increases, as wavelength ∝ 1/frequency). A large gravitational redshift is observed when radiation is emitted near or from objects with a strong gravitational field, such as neutron stars and black holes.

italics mine

So any photons escaping the strong gravitational field  (a black hole has a very strong gravitational field) will redshift i.e. lose energy while escaping.

You ask:

> would the same phenomenon occurs with a micro black hole?

yes,  a micro black hole has a gravitational field out of which  escaping photons  will lose energy but to measure the redshift would be an impossible task as from where would the atomic spectra come about a micro black hole to have enough photons for a spectral analysis?

One  applies to black hole radiation the knowledge of red-shifted photons observed in stars where spectra of various atoms exist in abundance and the photons leaving those spectra can be measured on earth and the red-shift determined. [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Overview) does not come from atomic spectra, but from the fields at the horizon.

> can the hawking radiation be blue shifted?

By the structure of hawking radiation, no. From where would the energy come to a photon getting out of a gravitational field?